# parsing and purpose of oracle audit (.aud) logs

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, audit

I am looking at the oracle audit logs and am trying to understand and parse.

The format appears to be consistent:

```
Date
Length:
Action:
...etc
```

My questions are: 1) what generates these? Is it every sql command executed against the db? 2) how can i parse these into a consistent format (xml/json/csv)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1) Audits are performed on actions you define.
For example: `audit all by testing by access` will audit everything that the user testing does.

2) I think you should look into XML auditing. [Source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o16security-085271.html)
Example:
Set up your database by issuing `alter system set audit_trail='XML, EXTENDED';`
This modification does require a DB restart.
After you set that you'll notice your audit files start coming in a format that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Audit xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/dbserver_audittrail-10_2.xsd" xmlns:
xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/
oracleas/schema/dbserver_audittrail-10_2.xsd">
  <Version>10.2</Version> 
  <AuditRecord>
    <Audit_Type>1</Audit_Type> 
    <Session_Id>108802</Session_Id> 
    <StatementId>9</StatementId> 
    <EntryId>1</EntryId> 
    <Extended_Timestamp>2005-10-09T00:20:02.284327</Extended_Timestamp> 
    <DB_User>SCOTT</DB_User> 
    <OS_User>oracle</OS_User> 
    <Userhost>prolin1</Userhost> 
    <OS_Process>22158</OS_Process> 
    <Terminal>pts/3</Terminal> 
    <Instance_Number>0</Instance_Number> 
    <Object_Schema>BANK</Object_Schema> 
    <Object_Name>ACCOUNTS</Object_Name> 
    <Action>103</Action> 
    <Returncode>0</Returncode> 
    <Scn>6447392335</Scn> 
    <SesActions>---------S------</SesActions> 
  </AuditRecord>
</Audit>
```

Once its in that format you'll find that you can do just about anything with it you like. Personally I send them to [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) for indexing, parsing, and handy searching.
Best of luck!

Comment: Unfortunatly, I need to analyze the non XML logs that already exist. 

I will take your advice and setup XML audit logs for the future. Any idea how I can parse the exisiting ones?

Comment: @oracle_novice, Well if the format you posted is what they are in then you could grep through them looking for something you want. Also the answer to question 1 is still the same. If you are curious about what objects or system privileges are audited investigate the `DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS` and `DBA_PRIV_AUDIT_OPTS` tables.

Comment: You can either audit to disk or to the database. If you want to write auditing reports you might find it easier if you audit to the database.

Comment: @Gandolf989, I'm not aware of how to write XML style auditing to a DB table. If XML is the desired format I believe OS is the only option (unless you feel like reinventing the wheel and placing some insert/update/delete triggers in place).

Comment: Do you need the data in an XML format? If not just query the underlying audit tables in the database to get what you want. If you do then Oracle has some XML support built in you just need to query for what you want and convert it to XML.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/auditing.htm#BCGIICFE